# Extracting matrix values from indices using Python

Tags: python, numpy

I want to access the elements of matrix `A` using `T` to yield a new matrix, `Anew` with the elements of `A` using Python. Is there a way to do it?

```
import numpy as np
A=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
T=array([[0, 2],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 0]],dtype=int64)
```

Desired output:

```
Anew=array([[3],
            [5],
           [4]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) -- the 1st column of T as row index, 2nd column of T as column index:

```
A[T[:,0], T[:,1]]
# array([3, 5, 4])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the arrays are numpy arrays, in Your case this can be solved with:

`A[T.T[0], T.T[1]]`